# copying jar files into multiple directories

Tags: bash, find, xargs, cp

I have written a bash script to copy the files into multiple directories but its not working.

```
find /usr/local/tomcat/ -not -path /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/test/WEB-INF  -type d  -name WEB-INF | xargs -n 1 echo cp /tmp/myjar.jar
```

The output of the find command is correct but the file is not getting copied. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Remove `echo` from the `xargs` command.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling `echo` in xargs command, just remove it and it should work

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your script. The `echo` command is not needed.
Replace it with this instead, just removing the command.

```
find /usr/local/tomcat/ -not -path /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/test/WEB-INF  -type d  -name WEB-INF | xargs -n 1 cp /tmp/myjar.jar
```